# getting error while calling function inside function - PHP

Tags: php, function, oop

while calling the function inside function i am getting error as

"**Fatal error: Call to undefined function getdb() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test1/function.php on line 41**"

the code is:

```
<?php  include "config.php" ?>
<?php
function get_all_records(){
    $con = getdb();   //it is line 41
    $Sql = "SELECT * FROM employeeinfo";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $Sql);
```

and **config.php** is

```
<?php
function getdb(){

try {

    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'projectdb');
     //echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(exception $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $conn;
}
?>
```

Can anybody help me out with the error. Thank You

**NOTE: already defined all the funtions, checked twice**

Comment: Try `require_once` instead of `include`, to make sure the file is actually included.

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will allow us to assist you with you question. There is not enough of your code to reproduce the problem. Without the MCVE it will be unlikely that you get the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @aynber thanks for suggestion but it didn't worked

Comment: Try putting the getdb() function definition into the same file to begin with, once it works there, then separate into another file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should try this:

```
function get_all_records($con) {
    $Sql = "SELECT * FROM employeeinfo";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $Sql);  ...
```

and:

```
get_all_records(getdb());
```

But, if you ask me, I suggest to you use class (object oriented way) instead of function.

Comment: it doesn't work. Thanks for suggestion though. Is class is better than function ?